# Set command for updating cassandra database

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra database with a keyspace name CS_DATA and Column family name ScheduledData with a supercolumn with cdata and row key as 'Div/12345/Plan 3'. This supercolumn has 2 columns with say c1 and c2 with some values. Each column ie c1 and c2 have value field. c1 has blank value and c2 has a value with many fields in it .

Something like this

```
value=<nodeId=123#time=12:34#location=bangalore>
```

how do i change the value of these 3 fields using the set command in cassandra database?

I tried the following on client side of cassandra

set CS_DATA.ScheduledData['Div/12345/Plan 3']['cdata']['c2']='nodeId=123'

This sets my c2 value as nodeId 123 but I need to change the sub field alone and retain my other two fields time and location same . How do I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using CQL instead? http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html

Comment: which cassandra version are you using?

Comment: Sir apache cassandra -version I am not sure :)

Comment: run `./bin/cassandra -v` to see the version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your design you have some serialized data like time and location inserted into C2 field. Well the outmost structure visible to Cassandra-Cli is c2. Unfortunately, you have to read the previous value stored in C2, deserialize it using the same algorithm your application is using to serialize that field and then insert it into C2 again.

Your design promotes doing read before write which is unfortunately is not great. Consider using column names like this so that you can separately change them:

c2_field1, c3_field_2, ...